# Split list of two nested lists in two separated lists - Prolog

Tags: list, split, prolog

I've done my research already and I can't find anything similar. I need to split a list of two lists in two separated lists, for example: [ [[1,2],[2],[3]], [[3], [2,3], [5]] ] -> results in [[1,2],[2],[3]] and [[3], [2,3], [5]] .

I tried this but I can't seem to find where I need to change the code:

```
split([],[],[]).
split([H|T],X,Y):-
   X = H,
   Y = T.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just unpack the list in two parameters:

```
split([L1, L2], L1, L2).
```

Here we thus unify the first parameter with `[L1, L2]` such that the list of length two is unified in that way that `L1` unifies with the first item (sublist), and `L2` with the second item (sublist).

Comment: So would it just stay  like this? I can't get the code functioning 
`
split([],[],[]).
split([L1, L2], L1, L2).
`

Comment: @MadPat: why do you need `split([],[],[])` here? In the question, it says as a pre-condition that the first list has (exactly) two elements.

Comment: You're right. But how do I put my list's name in [L1, L2]? Because I need to split an argument (inside a predicate)

Comment: What do you mean? You just call it, for example with `split([ [[1,2],[2],[3]], [[3], [2,3], [5]] ] , X, Y)`.

Comment: It was a . instead of a , ! What a beginner! Thank you very much